# how to implement link list in C++ using array?

Tags: c

I want to implement simple Link List in C Language using array. I have tried with so many website but unable to learn it, Can anyone please help out for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, please go through the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what kind of questions should be asked here.

Comment: Tagged as `c` and would like a `c++` answer but no effort in writing ones own homework. -1 from me

Comment: What is the point in making array a linked list? Array does not need links. They already reside in contiguous memory locations.

Comment: @cppcoder - You can do and it has an application when you cannot put stuff on the heap

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, then you do not call it a linked list. Its an array of structures

Comment: @cppcoder - First item in the pigeon hole of the list is the index (pointer) to the next. Just like memory. But it has fixed bounds and does not have the problem of being fractured

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement a linked list using a array of structure,

```
struct linknode
{
 int data;
 int next;
}
```

then craete a array,

```
struct linknode list[50];
```

then you have the head pointer having the index of first element; for exapmle

```
int head=0;
```

then for each node, for example to add a node at the 1st position of list use,

```
list[i].data=data;
list[i].next=head;
head=i;
```

here the next field will contain the array index of the next node. and last node can have,

```
list[last].next=-1;
```

you'll need to mange empty nodes by making it with -1 or by using `free list`.
This concept can give you idea to implement linked list using array, you can code in similar way as it is done for linked list with dynamically allocated nodes..

Comment: Can you tell me the use of `next` field in the `struct linknode`?

Comment: @nitish712 it will contain the link to the next node. for array implementation it will contain the array index of next node.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that each element in the array *is* a node (e.g. each element is a `struct` with both a value and a next node pointer, or even "next index") - in this aspect, it is *not* fundamentally different than a more traditional linked list implementation with `malloc/free`.

Now, imagine that there are *two* linked lists. One is the list of the actual "data", and the other is a linked list containing just the nodes that are available/free/not used. Setup this linked list of "free nodes" at the start (trivially, each node/element "points to" the next element in the array).

Then, to add a node new node to the "data" linked list, take the head node from the "free nodes" list (removing it of course) and use it, just as in any other linked list implementation. The difference from a more traditional malloc approach is that the "new node" function returns a free node/element from the array; and this is trivially handled with a "free nodes" list.